# Java Poor Performance GC Lots of Objects

Tags: java, performance, memory, garbage-collection

I am working with an application that needs to de-searlize 1000's of objects per second, validate them against a postgres database and then re-serialize the data to be sent to the next process using SQS.  What I keep observing is that after an hour or so I start getting lots of timed out db connections from my connection pool.  I think this is being caused by long garbage collection times as my heap space is maxed out.  GC runs every few seconds causing a noticeable lag.  It appears that java is not able to keep up with the number of objects that need to be created / destroyed and that once the initial heap allotment  runs out and the GC needs to start running more often and more aggressively everything breaks down.

What are best practices for applications that need to create / destroy large amounts of objects with high thoughput?

This is the output from jstat when the machine was in the bad state:

```
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
780288.0 800768.0  0.0    0.0   3015680.0 3015680.0 9313280.0  9312970.9  55680.0 54500.5 6272.0 6013.2    470  101.671  390  6241.164 6342.835
780288.0 800768.0  0.0    0.0   3015680.0 3015680.0 9313280.0  9312970.9  55680.0 54500.5 6272.0 6013.2    470  101.671  390  6241.164 6342.835
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to **re**-serialize? Why isn't it possible to send the original serialized data to the next process?

Comment: There are abundant reasons to avoid Java serialization wherever possible, and especially for high-throughput applications.  Consider instead implementing an appropriate lightweight protocol for externalizing and exchanging the state of the relevant objects.

Comment: You appear to be getting in the order of 16 second full collections and you having one every 10 - 20 s. I suspect your object are creating far more than one object each. What forma of serialization are you using as Java Serialization is one of the most expensive and produces the most garbage.

Comment: "I think this is being caused by long garbage collection times" - The first best practice is to actually measure and track down the cause of the problem. Doctoring about based on gut feeling is prone to lead your efforts in the wrong direction.

Comment: We are deseralizing one type of json object using gson, that is being used to construct a second type of domain object that is then serialized again using gson to be passed along to the next application in the pipeline.